# upload a large number of file to java app

Tags: java, ftp, payara

I have an application in payara that need to receive thousands of files
I was thinking to manage them using an ftp server to upload the files in a dir created run-time with temporary access.
I was looking to vsftpd, and virtual users, and means that I will need to generate new user by adding them to the users file, using htpasswd format: can someone suggest the best way to do it (I don't like the idea to execute a script on the system called by java).

### EDIT

At the moment I'm receiving the files using fileUpload component of primefaces, but it become unusable when more than 1.000 files are selected
That's why I'm not comfortable using any HTML interface

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with requiring users to use modern browsers, you can use the [HTML5 file input attribute `multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#attr-multiple), which will open a browser window allowing the user to select multiple files:

```
<input type="file" name="uploads" multiple>
```

You can then use [Apache's commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.html) to parse the `HttpServletRequest` and extract all the files, then do with them what you want.

This is way easier than setting up an alternative upload mechanism and start syncing it.

Comment: At the moment I'm already using fileUpload component of primefaces, but it get unstable when you upload more than 1000 files

Comment: Mentioning that in the question would have probably saved time for both you and me :-). If you're looking into requiring a non-browser client, then you can just as well roll your own and write something that batches uploads into smaller parts, similar to how the AWS CLI batches `s3 sync` operations.

Comment: Sorry for non mentioning before :( . I have no control on client side, so I would like to offer an alternative to upload the files